# AWS elastic beanstalk deployment issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cakephp-3.0

Getting below error while deploying cakephp application through elastic beanstalk-

```
Command failed on instance. Return code: 137 Output: (TRUNCATED)...sitories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh: line 37: 17807 Killed composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction $PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Comment: Did you "check /var/log/eb-activity.log" for more detail?

Comment: Figured it out mysql, it was an issue with memory limit, you need to keep it high a bit for composer updates.